# NTLM web service call to sharepoint 2013 web application with claim authentication over NTLM users

Tags: web-services, error, security, claims-based-auth, ntlm

I have a webservice (no vcf) with Windows authentication(impersonate="true"), that uses the SharePoint 2013 Object Model.

When I call a webservice method that operates on a SharePoint Web Application with NTLM authentication (created with PowerShell) all goes well.

When I call a webservice method that operates on a SharePoint Web Application with Claims authentication (created with Claims authentication type: Enable windows authentication -> Integrated Windows authentication -> NTLM) all goes well only for the user of Central Admin Application Pool.

I make my user: Farm Admin, Site Collection admin, Site Owner, ... but nothing changes.

My caller is an Active Directory user with no Kerberos authentication enabled, but all the development environment is inside a single computer.

I am new to claims authenticaion. Do I have to modify the webservice code/web.config?

I have an error when I try to get Title/Name info inside the following code:

```
   spsSite = New SPSite(strUrl)
   If strUrl.Equals(spsSite.Url, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
         'strTitle = spsSite.RootWeb.Title
         strTitle = spsSite.RootWeb.Name
         …
         Return 0
   End If
```

Inside log I can see the following (System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied):

```
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 General                            6t8b       
> Verbose     Looking up  site http://winsrv12ign in the farm
> SharePoint_Config       05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 General                
> 6t8d        Verbose     Looking up the additional information about
> the typical site http://winsrv12ign.   05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 General 
> 6t8f        Verbose     Site lookup is replacing http://winsrv12ign
> with the alternate access url http://winsrv12ign.       05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.47 General                            6t8g        Verbose    
> Looking up typical site http://winsrv12ign:80/ in web application
> SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 80.  05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 General
> 6t8h        Verbose     Found typical site /
> (26e8fdd4-662b-4518-b998-10ffba370941) in web application
> SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 80.        05/09/2013 13:02:22.47
> General                            narq        Verbose     Releasing
> SPRequest with allocation Id {CD815621-4839-49A7-B461-B4D5E2CB4E16}   
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 Upgrade                            ajyiy      
> Verbose     05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 w3wp (0x0EAC) 0x1A54 SharePoint
> Foundation Upgrade SPManager ajyiy VERBOSE Using cached
> [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] NeedsUpgrade value: False.
> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000        05/09/2013 13:02:22.47
> Upgrade                            ajyix       Verbose     05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.47 w3wp (0x0EAC) 0x1A54 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
> SPManager ajyix VERBOSE Using cached [SPContentDatabase
> Name=WSS_Content] IsBackwardsCompatible value: True.
> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 Database
> tzku        Verbose             ConnectionString: 'Data
> Source=WINSRV12IGN;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: NULL ConnectionState:
> Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15       05/09/2013 13:02:22.47 Database    
> ahjqp       Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.261555588768964 
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.48 Monitoring                         nasq       
> Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPSqlClient). Parent No       
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.48 Database                           tkeb       
> Verbose     Setting database session for
> dcb25be4-2aff-4013-be82-f70843083df3 and site
> 26e8fdd4-662b-4518-b998-10ffba370941.   05/09/2013 13:02:22.48
> Database                           tzku        Verbose            
> ConnectionString: 'Data Source=WINSRV12IGN;Initial
> Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition:
> 26e8fdd4-662b-4518-b998-10ffba370941 ConnectionState: Closed
> ConnectionTimeout: 15  05/09/2013 13:02:22.48 Database                
> ahjqp       Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.216228598886171 
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.49 Monitoring                         nasq       
> Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPSqlClient). Parent SPSqlClient
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.49 Database                           tkeb       
> Verbose     Setting database session for
> dcb25be4-2aff-4013-be82-f70843083df3 and site
> 26e8fdd4-662b-4518-b998-10ffba370941.   05/09/2013 13:02:22.49
> Database                           tzku        Verbose            
> ConnectionString: 'Data Source=WINSRV12IGN;Initial
> Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition:
> 26e8fdd4-662b-4518-b998-10ffba370941 ConnectionState: Closed
> ConnectionTimeout: 15  05/09/2013 13:02:22.49 Database                
> ahjqp       Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.0911428687165548       
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.49 Monitoring                         b4ly       
> Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient). Execution
> Time=4,28762594128583          05/09/2013 13:02:22.49 Monitoring      
> nass        Verbose             ____Execution Time=4,28762594128583   
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.49 Monitoring                         nass       
> Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=5328288           05/09/2013 13:02:22.49
> General                            8xfr        Verbose            
> PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x08000000, have 0x00000000   
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 Monitoring                         b4ly       
> Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient). Execution
> Time=15,3333035343878          05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 Monitoring      
> nass        Verbose             ____Execution Time=15,3333035343878   
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 Monitoring                         nass       
> Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=22067409          05/09/2013 13:02:22.50
> General                            8xfr        Verbose            
> **PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x2000010000, have 0x00000000** 
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                            8e2s       
> Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information:
> 0x80070005      05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                        
> aix9j       High                SPRequest.OpenWeb: UserPrincipalName=,
> AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://winsrv12ign           05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.50 General                            ai1wu       Medium     
> **System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.** (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Name()     at
> itConsult.ItcFramework.ItcSharePoint2013.SPSManager.iSPObjFromUrl(String
> strUrl, String& strTitle, SPObjType& esotSPObjctType, Int32&
> iIconInfo, String& strListType)     at
> itConsult.ItcFramework.ItcSharePoint2013.SPSManager.WebAppl_iSplitUrl(String
> strSPSBaseUrl, String strUrl, DataTable& dtUrlInfo, String& strErrors)
> at
> itConsult.ItcFramework.ItcSharePoint2013.SPSManager.WebAppl_iBaseUrlListSplitUrl(String[]
> astrSPSBaseUrls, String strUrl, DataTable& dtUrlInfo, String&
> strErrors)     at
> itConsult.josh.SPSWebService.SPSWebService.WebAppl_iBaseUrlListSplitUrl(String[]
> astrS...      05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                          
> ai1wu       Medium              ...PSBaseUrls, String strUrl,
> DataTable& dtUrlInfo)     at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)     at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)     at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
> target, Object[] values)     at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()     at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()  
> at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context)     at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHa...       
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                            ai1wu      
> Medium             
> ...ndlerFactory.HandlerWrapper.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
> at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
> error)     at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)     at
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)   
> at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32
> iWRType)       05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                         
> ftd0        Medium      Access Denied. Exception: Access is denied.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:  
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWeb(String
> bstrUrl, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, String& pbstrTitle, String&
> pbstrDescription, String& pbstrTitleResourceId, String&
> pbstrDescriptionResourceId, Guid& pguidID, DateTime& pdtTimeCreated,
> String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, Guid&
> pguidScopeId, UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32&
> pnLocale, UInt16& pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24, Int16& pnCollation,
> UInt32& pnCollationLCID, Int16& pnCalendarType, Int16&
> pnAdjustHijriDays, Int16& pnAltCalendarType, Boolean& pbShowWeeks,
> Int16& pnFirstWeekOfYear, UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek, Int16& pnWorkDays,
> Int16& pnWorkDayStartHour, Int16& pnWork...          05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.50 General                            ftd0        Medium     
> ...DayEndHour, Int16& pnMeetingCount, Int32& plFlags, Boolean&
> bConnectedToPortal, String& pbstrPortalUrl, String& pbstrPortalName,
> Int32& plWebTemplateId, Int16& pnProvisionConfig, String&
> pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String&
> pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String&
> pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String&
> pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String&
> pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String&
> pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor,
> UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean& bUserIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& bHasUniquePerm,
> Guid& pguidUserInfoListID, Guid& pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32&
> plSiteFlags, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime&
> pdtLastSecurityChange, String& pbstrWelcomePage, Boolean& p...        
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                            ftd0       
> Medium              ...bOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled,
> String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion,
> Int32& plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion,
> Int32& plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16&
> pnClientTag, Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& pgSourceSiteId, DateTime&
> pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppProductId,
> String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String&
> pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String&
> pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId,
> Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, UInt64& pmaskDeny)  
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWeb(String bstrUrl,
> String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, String& pbstrTitle, String&
> pbstrDescription, String& pbstrTi...       05/09/2013 13:02:22.50
> General                            ftd0        Medium             
> ...tleResourceId, String& pbstrDescriptionResourceId, Guid& pguidID,
> DateTime& pdtTimeCreated, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32&
> pwebVersion, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32&
> pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, UInt16& pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24,
> Int16& pnCollation, UInt32& pnCollationLCID, Int16& pnCalendarType,
> Int16& pnAdjustHijriDays, Int16& pnAltCalendarType, Boolean&
> pbShowWeeks, Int16& pnFirstWeekOfYear, UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek,
> Int16& pnWorkDays, Int16& pnWorkDayStartHour, Int16& pnWorkDayEndHour,
> Int16& pnMeetingCount, Int32& plFlags, Boolean& bConnectedToPortal,
> String& pbstrPortalUrl, String& pbstrPortalName, Int32&
> plWebTemplateId, Int16& pnProvisionConfig, String& pbstrDefaultTheme,
> String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl,
> String& pbstr...          05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General              
> ftd0        Medium              ...AlternateCSSUrl, String&
> pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String&
> pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String&
> pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String&
> pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor,
> UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean& bUserIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& bHasUniquePerm,
> Guid& pguidUserInfoListID, Guid& pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32&
> plSiteFlags, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime&
> pdtLastSecurityChange, String& pbstrWelcomePage, Boolean&
> pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String&
> pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion, Int32&
> plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion, Int32&
> plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag,
> Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& p...      05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General 
> ftd0        Medium              ...gSourceSiteId, DateTime&
> pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppProductId,
> String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String&
> pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String&
> pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId,
> Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, UInt64& pmaskDeny). 
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                            6t8b       
> Verbose     Looking up context  site
> http://winsrv12ign:990/SPSWebService.asmx in the farm
> SharePoint_Config          05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General             
> 88gr        Verbose             alternateUrl is null     05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.50 Database                           tzku        Verbose    
> ConnectionString: 'Data Source=WINSRV12IGN;Initial
> Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: NULL ConnectionState:
> Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15       05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 Database    
> ahjqp       Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.172368275856289 
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General                            adyrv      
> High        Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri
> http://winsrv12ign:990/SPSWebService.asmx.   05/09/2013 13:02:22.50
> Topology                           88gs        Verbose            
> hostHeaderSiteInfo is null          05/09/2013 13:02:22.50 General    
> 88gr        Verbose             alternateUrl is null     05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.51 Database                           tzku        Verbose    
> ConnectionString: 'Data Source=WINSRV12IGN;Initial
> Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: NULL ConnectionState:
> Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15       05/09/2013 13:02:22.51 Database    
> ahjqp       Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.116495252888286 
> 05/09/2013 13:02:22.51 General                            adyrv      
> High        Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri
> http://winsrv12ign:990/SPSWebService.asmx.   05/09/2013 13:02:22.51
> Topology                           88gs        Verbose            
> hostHeaderSiteInfo is null          05/09/2013 13:02:22.51 General    
> af32w       Unexpected  Could not load SPIisSettings for
> http://winsrv12ign:990/SPSWebService.asmx.       05/09/2013
> 13:02:22.51 General                            narq        Verbose    
> Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id
> {7BD65E26-2089-43D1-90BB-59EE4A394F93}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try out claims/kerberos? Neither classic/ntlm nor claims/ntlm supports delegation. Potentially this is causing the access denied.

Also check out this post:
[Is Classic/NTLM based authentication a security riskfor Internet facing sites?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28491/is-classic-ntlm-based-authentication-a-security-riskfor-internet-facing-sites)